# How to organize similar routes for multiple Rails users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, path, routes

Let's say I have an `Accountant < User` model, and a `Worker < User` model. They both need to have pages like 'Settings', 'Dashboard', etc.

Right now the paths are assigned and explicitly defined in `routes.rb`:

```
 resources :accountants
 get '/accountant/dashboard' => 'accountant#dashboard'
 get '/accountant/dashboard/:date' => 'accountant#dashboard'
 get '/accountant/settings' => 'accountant#settings'

resources :workers
get '/worker/dashboard' => 'worker#dashboard'
get '/worker/dashboard/:date' => 'worker#dashboard'
get '/worker/settings' => 'worker#settings'
```

Saving the "home" dashboard path in a session / as application level helper methods which rely on current user class both don't seem very Ruby-esque. Is there an alternative to this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way for this situation is NameSpace, Rails provide us something called namespace and you can use it in the routes for generate different routes for different views in your case maybe works something like that:

```
namespace :accountants do
  get 'dashboard'
  get 'dashboard/:date'
  get 'settings'
end

namespace :workers do
  get 'dashboard'
  get 'dashboard/:date'
  get 'settings'
end
```

and that will generate a routes like that:

```
localhost:3000/accountants/1/dashboard

localhost:3000/workers/1/settings
```

it's just and example you always can read the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) about it, but it's a good way for organize your different routes thinking in the scalability.

Another option is using roles to manage the different users you have because of you extend of user model is not scalable with the time and it's going to be a little confuse in the future read this code

Regards !

Comment: Thanks for the response. Isn't slamming a bunch of code into `User` model worse over time though?